# Structural search and replace with new variable

Tags: intellij-idea, server-side-rendering

using idea 2019.2 I am not able to do structural search and replace of for eg convert static lowerfieldnames to uppercase. I can not insert the variable containing the lowercase into the replace template

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have defined the variable with name `methodName`, use Groovy script with the `methodName.getText().toLowerCase()` expression that will replace the text of the method name to all lower case.

Check the examples in documentation here: [Convert uppercase values of the class attribute in p tags to lowercase](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#convert-uppercase-values-of-the-class-attribute-in-p-tags-to-lowercase)

Comment: this does not work as I mentioned. it gives me the error „Malformed replacement pattern Replacement variable is not defined.

Comment: Try the [early access program](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) for the next version, this is fixed there.